# app downloaded not installed but storage card memory decreased

Tags: storage

I downloaded an app from playstore app was downloaded but not installed Ab error message flashed can't install app on USB or storage card.
But my storage card memory was decreased.I tried again but again memory card storage was decreased.I cleared cache,rebooted phone,clear playstore n play services data n cache,searched gor files using file storage but can't find anything,its been 2 days know.

Comment: To be clear, you have less room on your external storage not your main intenral storage?  An /sdcard  or /external partition for example?  Did you use a [file manager](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=cm+file+manager&c=apps) to look in /data/data (internal storage) o see if the file was there?  Did you look in the /sdcard/Android and /sdcard/Downloads directory for unnecessary files related to the uninstallable app?  If this is a huge amount of storage, and you can't find where it is, you can always reformat.

Comment: Yes it is external card and I can't find file using file manager.also it is huge amount of data so finding file is difficult.are these kind of files visible.

Comment: Not sure where the app is downloaded before it's installed, but when you say you cleared cache, you cleared the play store/services' cache too, right?  What version of Android?  And which device?  Do you see any messages in [logcat](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Logcat) when you try to re-install the file?  If you have root, you can use the command `find /data -type f -size +500k -exec ls -l {} \;` to identify possible larger files that relate to the app.  (change +500k to the min size or change /data to /sdcard if you want to look there).  remove `-exec ls -l {} \;` for the raw path w/o size.

Comment: I m using HTC Desire.I cleared playstore and play services cache.I searched for files in data ,download and android folder by download dates but I believe file is not visible.I guess I wud have to format card